# What's the difference between StaticLayout and DynamicLayout

Tags: android, layout

I understand that `DynamicLayout` is intended for a Layout that has its text being changed, whereas `StaticLayout` deals with an immutable text.

However, the two classes mostly have the same methods, according to their docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/DynamicLayout.html

Specifically, I don't see a method `setText()` on the `DynamicLayout` class.

What is their difference, and how can I use `DynamicLayout` to calculate layouts where the text ist changing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to be updated on text change, DynamicLayout expects Spannable as first parameter. In that case it creates instance of internal static class DynamicLayout.ChangeWatcher, and attaches it to the Spannable. The Spannable, in turn, needs to implement Editable in order to be updated.

Example:

```
SpannableStringBuilder base = new SpannableStringBuilder("a");
DynamicLayout dynamicLayout = new DynamicLayout(base, base, paint, width, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0, 0, true);
int firstHeight = dynamicLayout.getHeight();
base.append("\nA");
int secondHeight = dynamicLayout.getHeight();
```

Comment: hi, im trying to calculate height of different texts using same dynamicLayout. Currently i'm using a Single SpannableStringBuilder over which i call clear to remove text and append for adding new text. But DynamicLayout's line count keeps increasing. How can i reuse a single DynamicLayout and SpannableStringBuilder for measuring multiple texts?